# Formatting table with partitions

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the best way of only getting the rows between the occurrences opened and closed in PostgreSQL?

```
+------------+----+------------+---------------------+
|  event_id  | ID | occurrence |      datetime       |
+------------+----+------------+---------------------+
| 1003603017 | A  | owner_from | 12/16/2016 4:44:16  |
| 1003603017 | A  | owner_to   | 12/16/2016 4:44:38  |
| 1003603017 | A  | owner_from | 12/16/2016 4:44:38  |
| 1003603017 | A  | opened     | 12/16/2016 4:44:39  |
| 1003603017 | B  | owner_from | 12/16/2016 7:36:23  |
| 1003603017 | A  | owner_to   | 12/16/2016 7:36:23  |
| 1003603017 | B  | owner_to   | 12/16/2016 9:00:01  |
| 1003603017 | C  | owner_from | 12/16/2016 9:00:01  |
| 1003603017 | A  | closed     | 12/16/2016 12:00:36 |
| 1003603017 | D  | owner_from | 12/17/2016 4:25:00  |
| 1003603017 | C  | owner_to   | 12/17/2016 4:25:00  |
| 1003603017 | D  | owner_from | 12/17/2016 4:52:02  |
| 1003603017 | D  | owner_to   | 12/17/2016 4:52:02  |
| 1003603017 | D  | opened     | 12/17/2016 4:52:02  |
| 1003603017 | D  | owner_to   | 12/17/2016 8:57:00  |
| 1003603017 | E  | owner_from | 12/17/2016 8:57:00  |
| 1003603017 | D  | closed     | 12/17/2016 12:03:10 |
+------------+----+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: what do you want as output?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query used:

```
select * from t
inner join (select event_id, 
                   valid_from, 
                   valid_to 
            from (select event_id, 
                         id, 
                         occurrence, 
                         lead(occurrence) over (partition by event_id order by datetime) as next_occurrence, 
                         datetime as valid_from, 
                         lead(datetime) over (partition by event_id order by datetime) as valid_to 
                         from t 
                         where occurrence in ('opened','closed')) A 
           where occurrence = 'opened') t1 on t.event_id = t1.event_id and t1.valid_from <= t.datetetime and t.datetime <= t1.valid_to
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be so easy with the `ignore nulls` option on lag.  Here is another method that uses the cumulative maximum `datetime` for `opened` and `closed`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when occurrence = 'opened' then datetime end) over (order by datetime) as mr_opened,
             max(case when occurrence = 'closed' then datetime end) over (order by datetime) as mr_closed,
      from t
     ) t
where mr_opened > mr_closed;
```

Notes:

- This does not include the final `closed`.  The question is not clear on this requirement.
- You might want to partition by `event_id`.  The question is not clear on this requirement.
- In more recent versions of Postgres, you can use the `filter` syntax instead of `case`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT event_id, ID, occurrence, datetime       
FROM (
   SELECT event_id, ID, occurrence, datetime,       
          COUNT(CASE WHEN occurrence = 'opened' THEN 1 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY datetime) AS grp,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN occurrence = 'opened' THEN 1 END) 
             OVER (ORDER BY datetime)  - 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN occurrence = 'closed' THEN 1 END) 
             OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS slice
   FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.slice = 1 AND grp <> 1 ;
```

The first windowed conditional `COUNT` used helps identify not `opened` records that coincide with `opened` ones. Using the value of this field we can filter those records out.

The second calculated field uses a difference between running totals in the population of `opened`, `closed` trick to determine partitions starting with an `open` and terminating before a `closed` record.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/FETO14763)

Answer (score 0):

I made an inner join on itself selecting only the opened and closed occurrences with a lead on the closed and joining where the datetime in the original table is between those values.

Comment: I would be helpful if you could share your query with us. Also, how does it compare performance-wise with the queries of the two other answers?

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done with simple `JOIN`s (however it requires multiple):

```
select e.*
from   events o
join   events c on c.datetime > o.datetime
join   events e on e.datetime > o.datetime and e.datetime < c.datetime
where  o.occurrence = 'opened'
and    c.occurrence = 'closed'
and    not exists(select 1
                  from   events x
                  where  x.datetime > o.datetime
                  and    x.datetime < c.datetime
                  and    x.occurrence in ('opened', 'closed'));
```

This probably won't scale well as you add more rows to the table, but it has a possibility to use indexes.

Another option is to use window functions:

```
select (e).*
from   (select e, count(1) filter (where occurrence = 'opened') over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                - count(1) filter (where occurrence = 'closed') over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and current row) open_close
        from   events e) e
where  open_close = 1;
```

This one will always require a full table scan (but only one). Another difference is that if you don't have a closing `occurrence = 'closed'` row, the window variant will return the last rows after the last `occurrence = 'opened'`.

http://rextester.com/FZLV77431